# How to schedule a task using something other than Alarms and it should be easy to test and also should run even after device restart?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have to run a receiver which receives `action` `USER_PRESENT` only for a particular duration on specific days of the week. Here the duration and weekdays are selected by user.

What I have tried is using `Preferences` with `AlarmManager` to achieve this and I would very much like to use something other than `Alarms` with `Preferences` to achieve this as It becomes too difficult to test alarms with weekly alarms that runs after user selected duration and for user selected week days.

Is there any other way I can do this work other than using `Alarms` and `Preferences`. A code sample would really helpful !!

---

---

**For more details here is my approach using `Alarms` with `Preferences` :**

Now Firstly I calculate the start time by letting user choose the hour and minutes through a `DialogFragment` where a `TimePickerDialog` is inflated so that user can choose the starting time and I get the `hrs` and `min` in the `onTimeSet()` callback and then I find out the start time for the receiver to go off.

Code Snippet goes something like this for calculating start time in millis from `hrs` and `min`:

```
    Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
    //setting alarm from current day so that it starts from today onwards
    int day = calSet.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Long milliseconds = calSet.getTimeInMillis();
    //check if the time is already passed
    Long daily = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;
    if (milliseconds < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        //if already passed then push it for next day by adding just 24 hrs
        milliseconds = milliseconds + daily;
    }
```

And then I save this calculated time in millis in a `preference` say : `SharedPreferences.Editor.putLong("PeriodicLockStartTimeInMillis", milliseconds);`

Now I store the days user has selected using `checkBoxes` and setting  `preferences` for each day's checkbox

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.putBoolean("DAYNAME", true);
```

also storing the duration for which the user wants the receiver to work:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.putLong("LockDurationInMillis", minutesinmillis);
```

Then Using `AlarmManager` to set an alarm which will set a `BroadcastReceiver`  whose name here is `PeriodicLockService`as an `PendingIntent` that will hit its receiver .

Code for setting alarm here :

```
Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PeriodicLockService.class);
reminderIntent.setAction("ACTION_REPEATING_ALARM_RECEIVER");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), PeriodicLockService.REPEATING_ALARM_UNIQUE_ID, reminderIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds, pendingIntent);
} else {
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds, pendingIntent);
}
```

Now in `PeriodicLockService` when `onReceive` is hit then I firstly check if user had set things to run for today by using the `preference` as :

```
//Fetching today's day from Calendar to compare if user has set lock for today
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    switch (day) {
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, SUN_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, MON_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, TUES_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, WED_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, THURS_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, FRI_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            if (Preferences.getBooleanPreference(context, SAT_DAY)) {
                startLockNow(context);
            }
            break;
    }

private void startLockNow(Context context) {
    Long lockStartTimeInMillis = Preferences.getLongPreference(context, "PeriodicLockStartTimeInMillis");

    //Update Unlock Time
    Long LockDurationInMillis = Preferences.getLongPreference(context, "LockDurationInMillis"); //End time to stop the Receiver for action USER_PRESENT
    Long newEndTime = lockStartTimeInMillis + LockDurationInMillis;

    //Set Unlocked notification broadcast which also disables the receiver for action `USER_PRESENT`
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FinalUnlockedBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newEndTime + 1000, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newEndTime + 1000, pendingIntent);
    }

    //update the time for next lock by adding a day
    milliseconds = Preferences.getLongPreference(context, "PeriodicLockStartTimeInMillis") + 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;
    Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(context, PeriodicLockService.class);
    reminderIntent.setAction("ACTION_REPEATING_ALARM_RECEIVER");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REPEATING_ALARM_UNIQUE_ID, reminderIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds , pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds , pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

But the thing is this doesn't always seem to work and its difficult to get logs from users devices running my app.

Is there any other way I can do this work other than using `Alarms` and `Preferences`

Answer (score 1):

**Android-Job** [Android-Job repo](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

- Android-Job abstracts away which implementation you want to use to perform background work.
- Depending on the requirements, this library decides which API to use to run your job.
- It provides a superset of all the features from JobScheduler, GCMNetworkManager and AlarmManager.
- All features from Android Nougat are backward compatible.
- Less boilerplate.

Implementing Android-Job is super easy.

The API includes below classes/interfaces.

1. Job : Your jobs need to extend this class and override onRunJob method. The heavy lifting is done here. You must return a Result from this method so that the system knows whether to attempt to run your job at a later time.
2. JobRequest: You can schedule a Job by creating a JobRequest using its builder constructor and passing your Job tag.
3. JobCreator: JobCreator acts like a factory to provide a Job based on a job tag. Your concrete JobCreator class must implement the JobCreator interface and override the create method.
4. JobManager: The JobManager class serves as the entry point. Before using this class you must initialize this as singleton. JobManager takes a Context. After creating the instance, you have to add your JobCreator to JobManager.

if u interested to read more plz take alook to this awesome article [Easy Job Scheduling with Android-Job](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742)

thanks for **Rajesh Pattanaik** the person who wrote this article

Comment: So How do I schedule some work for exact selected day and time using this lib ?

Comment: inside article there is simple example https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742 try it ;)

Comment: The `setPeriodic()` can be used to schedule `jobs` for min 15 min later also the `JobManager.instance().getConfig().setAllowSmallerIntervalsForMarshmallow(true);` can't be used for Android M above so it makes it hard to test on..

Comment: I was testing this and found that it works well, I tested with 3 - 4 devices.. I will test some more. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you Firebase Job Dispatcher. It is a library for scheduling background jobs in your Android app. It provides a JobScheduler-compatible API that works on all recent versions of Android (API level 9+) that have Google Play services installed.

For instructions on how to use it in your app, click [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android).

Comment: I don't think this will work well for me. say I have to schedule things to run on mon, wed and sat of the week.. how can I use Firebase Job Dispatcher to achieve this. Or simply put how to schedule some work for exact selected day and time ?
can you show any code snippets to support your answer ?

Comment: @shadygoneinsane I think you are right, we can't schedule jobs for a particular time using Firebase Job Dispatcher :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Job Scheduler

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("sid", "Job scheduler called");
        jobFinished(params, true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call the below method in your activity

```
private void constructJob(){
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class));

        builder.setMinimumLatency(60000)
                .setBackoffCriteria(10000,JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setPersisted(true);

        mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
```

Make sure you call builder.setPersisted(true) in order to run the service even after reboot. Another thing to have a look is that this code will work fine on Android N (API 24) or above APIs, however, for API 21 - 23 it call builder.setPeriodic(60000) instead of builder.setMinimumLatency(60000)

**UPDATE**
In order to run Job Scheduler on API 15 and above use JobSchedulerCompat.

Add below dependency in your gradle file -

```
compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
```

Comment: I want a solution for Api 15 and above !!

Comment: I read about the backward compatibility lib and I found this :
1) Deprecated - Clearly written at the very beginning.
why would I wasted my time using something depreciated and read the second point - read on -
2) this library has not been well-tested, so I would advise not using in production at this time. There are no guarantees that this will not run down your battery or cause your device to explode.
I would use alarm manager instead.

Comment: The best option for you is to use Alarm Manager with Broadcast receiver.

Comment: That I am already aware of and have a working solution as you can see in the extended version of my app. Anyways thanks for the help.